# Error when I using SwiftUI with CoreData and 2 SQLite database files with same database structure

Tags: xcode, swiftui, core-data

I created SwiftUI project with coredata.
I duplicated PersistenceController to be PersistenceController2 that for handle 2nd SQLite file.

> Here is code of PersistenceController

```
import CoreData

class PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    let container: NSPersistentContainer

func urlApplicationSupportDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

func sqliteURL() -> URL {
    let url = urlApplicationSupportDirectory().appendingPathComponent("MM1.SQLite")
    return url
}

init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "testCoreData")

    if inMemory {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    }

    let url = sqliteURL()
    print(url.absoluteString)

    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
    description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
    description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
}
```

}

> PersistenceController2 is difference at filename only "MM1.SQLite" to be "MM2.SQLite"

> Then I create TabBarView like this code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabBarView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ContentView()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("1")
                    //Image("TabIcon"+"Account")
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet.rectangle.portrait")
                }
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)

            ContentView()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("2")
                    //Image("TabIcon"+"Account")
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet.rectangle.portrait")
                }
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController2.shared.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

When I comment 1st TabView and run only 2nd TabView, It can run correctly MM2.SQLite can store data normally.
When I command 2nd TabView and run only 1st TabView, It can run correctly MM1.SQLite can store data normally.

But the problem is ... When I opened comment and run both TabView, it cannot run and show message error like this below.

```
2022-12-07 21:06:41.411772+0700 testCoreData[38345:1010632] [error] warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'Item' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.
CoreData: warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'Item' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.
2022-12-07 21:06:41.412037+0700 testCoreData[38345:1010632] [error] warning:     'Item' (0x60000083c630) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600001c169e0) claims 'Item'.
CoreData: warning:       'Item' (0x60000083c630) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600001c169e0) claims 'Item'.
2022-12-07 21:06:41.412175+0700 testCoreData[38345:1010632] [error] warning:     'Item' (0x6000008306e0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600001c105a0) claims 'Item'.
CoreData: warning:       'Item' (0x6000008306e0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600001c105a0) claims 'Item'.
2022-12-07 21:06:41.412302+0700 testCoreData[38345:1010632] [error] error: +[Item entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
CoreData: error: +[Item entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
2022-12-07 21:06:41.557326+0700 testCoreData[38345:1010632] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'
```

May you help me for some suggestion to solved this error?

[Edit/Add more information]
Actually, I have an experience with multiple containers without SwiftUI. Please see below sample project that can run 2 containers with 2 database files "MM1.SQLite" and "MM2.SQLite". So if you all have some suggestions how to implement 2 container core data with SwiftUI, please help to suggest me.

[image: 1st container]

[image: 2nd container]

Comment: You should only have 1 container, a container can have multiple stores but it is the same container. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/setting_up_a_core_data_stack [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/linking_data_between_two_core_data_stores) is another link

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm newbie with SwiftUI.
Actually, I successful do like this code with NSFetchResultController. However, it may be not good coding style. 
I will research and learn more to manage 2 core data with same container.

Comment: I understand that one container is for one data model, is this correct?
However, in my case, I want to make one data model to be 2 database files. Of course, both files are same structure, but I will keep different data for some reasons.
May you please give me more suggestions?

Comment: The URL is attached to the store not the container https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/linking_data_between_two_core_data_stores in the model you can designate what store gets what entity  with the configuration. I am pretty sure you will need 2 entities but they can both conform to the same abstract entity so they match. If you don't have 2 entities CoreData will not know where to put the data.